# Password Regex Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validation-engine

I need a regex to validate a password input by the user through JS in an online registration form.  The criteria for the password is the following:

1. has to be longer than 8 characters
2. has to include at least 1 number, 1 lower case letter and 1 upper case letter
3. cannot include curly brackets {}
4. must allow any other special characters (like @, #, $, %, _, " etc.)
5. the order of the number, lowercase letters and upper case letters can be random, so it can be for example Ab1394*"  or *"bA1394

I have tried to use the following regex, however if you input any special character such as '?' before the curly bracket {, it would allow it as a valid input.  I am new to using regex and not really familiar so might be there's something minor in it:

```
^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[,#?!=@%&\^\$\*\)\(\_\.\'\"\+\-]).{8,}$
```

Can someone help me with a regex for this or point any issues in mine? Thanks

Comment: Why not allow curly brackets?

Comment: I have a limitation with a legacy system and I cannot allow those characters in a password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To easily forbid characters, change `.{8,}` to `[^{}]{8,}`:

```
^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*[,#?!=@%&\^\$\*\)\(\_\.\'\"\+\-])[^{}]{8,}$
```

Or include any authorized char within the class:

```
[a-zA-Z\d,#?!=@%&\^\$\*\)\(\_\.\'\"\+\-]{8,}
```